# UIActionSheet at appdelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to display a UIActionSheet at the beginning of my application so I descided to fire it in my appdelegate class , at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

using

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you wish to install test cases " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: @"Yes", @"No", nil];
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[popupQuery showInView:window];
[popupQuery release];
```

but it fire exception

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil'

how to fix that

best regards

Comment: i think its not because your action sheet because i used same code and its working fine at my end.

Comment: i just paste the above code in my didFinishlaunching and it works for me but my window has a view in it , does you have a view in window?

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or didFinishLaunching

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: it raise teh error I mentioned above

Comment: is your code running proper without this code?

Answer (score 0):

You should show it inside view, not inside window! It seems that there is no any view on your window.

Comment: `[popupQuery showInView:window];` — are you sure you are using `view` of `UIView` and not `window` in your `viewDidLoad:`?

Answer (score 0):

it will exactly works in my app.so NSInternalInconsistencyException means u would be so fast to click on various app like IB and Xcode and while running u would be tried to save file.so that causes inconsistency.just close and then open it will works.

check window outlet is connected or not in IB and also delegate.

Answer (score 0):

[popupQuery showFromRect:self.window.frame inView:self.window animated:YES];